# Веб-приложение (страничка) выгружается из памяти смартфона при открытии камеры

Tags: javascript, html, камера

Для получения изображения с камеры смартфона на вэб-странице использую стандартный HTML-тэг `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">` и дальше передаю его на сервер.

Но иногда при открытии приложения камеры смартфон просто-напросто выгружает страничку из памяти, то есть страничка ведет себя так, как буд-то произошел рефреш.

Может есть способ запретить браузеру или ОС выгружать вэб-страницу из памяти или при перезагрузке страницы не терять контекст приложения?

Comment: Это называется "кеш", регулируется заголовками Apache/Nginx.

Comment: Спасибо за направление! Можно поподробнее подсказать куда копать?